# Cap production deploy failed error: could not locate gemfile on AWS server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, capistrano

I am deploying a rails app on a AWS ec2 instance through Capistrano.
Cap production deploy:check is successful, but when I am running cap production deploy I get an error.

Can anyone help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you pushed the **Gemfile** and **Gemfile.lock** file to git?

Comment: yes every thing is up on github.

Comment: you can see my gist for creating a deploy script here: https://gist.github.com/imtiaz-emu/dcb87fde71a9562037d2

Comment: I think I have all the necessary codes. You can check  https://github.com/romanchsharma/sampleawsapp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Your Gemfile in the project was named "gemfile" SMALL g

It must be Gemfile. 
So the thing run on Mac and Windows. But when you deploy to Linux, it does not see the Gemfile.Please rename the "gemfile" in your project to "Gemfile"
It will work.